# How to make a button draggable/movable with SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5, swiftui

I am trying to make a Button Movable with SwiftUI. From what it looks like this should work. I have tried putting the Button with Text inside another ZStack and for a second it was working but as soon as I released the button, the dragging stopped and I couldn't drag anymore. I noticed that the tap was remaining in the center despite the button had moved. Also the dragging looked buggy.

```
 struct CircleButton: View {
@State private var dragAmount = CGSize.zero
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Button(action: performAction){
            ZStack {
                Circle()
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                Text("Move me")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(.system(.caption, design: .serif))
            }
        }
        .animation(.default)
        .offset(self.dragAmount)
    }
    .gesture(
        DragGesture()
            .onChanged { self.dragAmount = $0.translation})
}

func performAction(){
    print("button pressed")
 }
}
```

I tried this:

```
struct CircleButton: View {
@State private var dragAmount = CGSize.zero
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        ZStack {
            Button(action: performAction){
                Circle()
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            }
            Text("Tap me")
        }
        .offset(self.dragAmount)
        .animation(.default)
    }
    .gesture(
        DragGesture()
            .onChanged{ self.dragAmount = $0.translation})
}

func performAction(){
    print("button pressed")
 }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a demo of possible approach.

#### Update: re-tested with Xcode 13.3 / iOS 15.4

[image: demo]

See also notes inline.

```
struct CircleButton: View {
    @State private var dragAmount: CGPoint?
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { gp in // just to center initial position
            ZStack {
                Button(action: self.performAction) {
                    ZStack {
                        Circle()
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                        Text("Move me")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(.system(.caption, design: .serif))
                    }
                }
                 // Use .none animation for glue effect
                .animation(.default, value: dragAmount)
                .position(self.dragAmount ?? CGPoint(x: gp.size.width / 2, y: gp.size.height / 2))
                .highPriorityGesture(  // << to do no action on drag !!
                    DragGesture()
                        .onChanged { self.dragAmount = $0.location})
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity) // full space
        }
    }

    func performAction() {
        print("button pressed")
    }
}
```

Comment: One question: when I deleted the .frame() menthod you added at the bottom, I noticed that the result was the same. Is there a reason why it would be needed? I see that the comment next to it says full space but I am not sure what it meant.

Comment: @OcielLerma, it remains from initial tries, where there was no GeometryReader used, so it should be if to remove that. But if you keep it as present, then you can safely remove .frame modifier.

Comment: Use `.animation(.none)` to stop the drag from lagging behind

Answer (score 4):

I found a simple solution here by [ohayon](https://gist.github.com/ohayon/83305d9c48e4fc3e7c3851ba10ddc4c9)  . Just a ViewModifier and an extension:

```
struct DraggablePita: View {
  var body: some View {
    Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "pita.png")!)
      .draggable() // Add the new, custom modifier to make this draggable
  }
}

// Handle dragging
struct DraggableView: ViewModifier {
  @State var offset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

  func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    content
      .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
        .onChanged { value in
          self.offset.x += value.location.x - value.startLocation.x
          self.offset.y += value.location.y - value.startLocation.y
      })
      .offset(x: offset.x, y: offset.y)
  }
}

// Wrap `draggable()` in a View extension to have a clean call site
extension View {
  func draggable() -> some View {
    return modifier(DraggableView())
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

how about something different and concise:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    CircleButton()
}
}

struct CircleButton: View {

@State private var pos = CGPoint(x:222,y:222) // just for testing

var body: some View {
    theButton.position(self.pos).highPriorityGesture(self.drag)
}

var theButton: some View {
    ZStack {
        Circle()
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .onTapGesture { self.performAction() }
        Text("Tap me")
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .font(.system(.caption, design: .serif))
    }
}

func performAction(){
    print("button pressed")
}

var drag: some Gesture {
    DragGesture().onChanged { value in self.pos = CGPoint(x: value.location.x, y: value.location.y)}
}
}
```

Comment: `highPriorityGesture` solved my issue.