# How can I update the location X for offset in exact tap point for a view in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to update my Rec offset with drag Gesture of this Rec, I already coded in this way that the Rec start moving itself depending on drag and follow the drag as I coded, the problem that I get with this is it get centered itself always and I can not drag Rec out of screen, my goal is coding in way that offset start working with inter location of tag and it become the source for offset, now the source is center, which I like to be dynamic and be flexible as tap on Rec. How I should code this?
[image]

```
    struct ContentView: View {
    

    @State var locationX: CGFloat = .zero
    let widthOfRec: CGFloat = 200
    
    var body: some View {

        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.red)
            .frame(width: widthOfRec)
            .border(Color.black)
            .offset(x: locationX - widthOfRec/2)
            .gesture( DragGesture().onChanged { value in locationX = value.location.x })
        
        
        
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understood your goal you need to use `GestureState`. The gesture state has temporary value which reset back to initial once gesture finished.

Here is a demo of possible solution. Prepared with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

[image: demo]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var locationX: CGFloat = .zero
    @GestureState private var translationX = CGFloat.zero

    let widthOfRec: CGFloat = 200
    
    var body: some View {

        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.red)
            .frame(width: widthOfRec)
            .border(Color.black)
            .offset(x: locationX + translationX)
            .gesture(
                DragGesture().updating($translationX) { value, state, _ in
                    state = value.translation.width
                }.onEnded { value in
                    locationX += value.translation.width
                }
            )
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks that was exactly what I wanted, one last question, could we get same result with using position instead of offset? If it does not bother you please show me that code as well. thanks again

Comment: Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/61264855/12299030

Comment: thanks that was also great, for moving view tasks which one is better and recommended? offset or position? as I can see and learnt I can use both way right now, but how I could decide which one is right for the job?

Comment: The position modifier changes real frame and thus affects all layout, the offset changes only drawing place (ie. real view remains at the same place). The choice is not about better-worse, but about what behavior is need in specific scenario.